# Unable to start call with azure communication service rooms

Tags: javascript, azure, videocall, azure-communication-services

I have created a sample application for Azure Communication Service Rooms.
I have created a room with the participant and i am trying to start the call by joining the room immediately or by providing the roomid.
When I call the `callagent.Join`

```
const roomCallLocator = { roomId: roomId }
call = callAgent.join(roomCallLocator, { videoOptions })
```

call agent starts the call initializes the video stream and then disconnects it by throwing an error user is not part of the invite list.
But i have checked with `roomsClient.listParticipants(roomid)` the participant is there.

When i have added participant manually as well to the call object using following code:

```
const participantsList = await roomsClient.listParticipants(roomId)
console.log('\nRetrieved participants for room:')
    
    
for await (const participant of participantsList) {
   call.addParticipant(participant.id)    
}
```

but still, it starts the call and ends the call immediately throwing error `'code: 403 subCode: 5828'` which is user is not part of invite list.

Actual Exception in logs:

> 5e46e33213be","callType":2,"callDirection":"Outgoing","failureReason":"CallSetupError","callEndDiagnosticsInfo":{"callControllerCode":403,"callControllerSubCode":5828,"phrase":"The join is not authorized for Acs Room System since user is not part of invitee list."

With this [QuickStart example on MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/rooms/join-rooms-call?pivots=platform-web) same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it, I ran into the same issue. I followed these steps, and it worked for me:

Generate an identity:

```
az communication identity token issue --scope voip --connection-string "your connection string"

az communication rooms create --valid-from "2024-03-25T10:21" --valid-until "2024-03-28T10:21" --pstn-dial-out-enabled "False" --connection-string "your connection string"

az communication rooms participant add-or-update --attendee-participant "user id" --room "roomId" --connection-string "your connection string"
```

In the example I used the token generate in step 1 and the room id from step 2

[image]

Comment: were you able to join the room and start video call? please share gif or png in your answer.

Comment: Yes, I was able to keep video working with the call.  Before posting my answer, I set up a 2nd environment to review the steps and it worked on that environment as well